# How to properly setup factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, factory, angularfire

I'm attempting to move my Firebase authentication logic from a controller to a factory, but running into problems with basic setup. I'm using Angularfire to accomplish authentication in my app, and have followed the documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html).

Everything worked fine in my controller, but I'm not sure how to properly set the code up in a factory. My current code is below:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('authService', authService);

authService.$inject = ['$firebaseAuth'];

var ref = new Firebase('https://[MY-FIREBASE].firebaseio.com');
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

return {
    createUser(email,password): auth.$createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).then(function(userData) {
        $location.path('/people');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }),

    connectFacebook: auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
        $location.path('/places');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert("Authentication failed:", error);
    }),

    removeUser: auth.$removeUser({
        email: vm.email,
        password: vm.password
    }).then(function() {
        alert('User removed');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error);
    })
}
```

What I'm aiming to do is inject this factory into my login controller and wire up click events that call the appropriate functions, such as `authService.createUser($scope.email,$scope.password);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be more of a use case for having a service instead of a factory.

It's much easier to setup a factory/service with the function syntax, rather than this object style.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.service('AuthService', function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://[MY-FIREBASE].firebaseio.com');
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  this.createUser = function(email, password) {
    // ...
  };

  this.connectFacebook = function() {
    // ...
  };

  this.removeUser = function(email, password) {
    // ...
  };
})
```

A service exposes whatever was attached to `this`, we can inject it and use it elsewhere in our application.

```
.controller('AuthController', function($scope, AuthService) {
  $scope.email = '';
  $scope.password = '';

  $scope.register = function() {
    AuthService.createUser($scope.email, $scope.password); 
  };
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I honestly hadn't fully grasped the usefulness of services until this explanation. Many courses and tutorials do a disservice by glossing over services and saying "factories will be the best option in almost all cases". For this reason I was constantly looking to bend factories to my needs, not anymore!

Comment: The landscape of Angular tutorials can be confusing. I still haven't found one that I consider to have a crystal clear distinction between the use cases, but I've come up with my own set of rules that work fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my factory looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('RegistrationFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var urlBase = '/api/';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.IsRegistered = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    };

    dataFactory.RegisterUser = function (username, password, deviceId) {
        var RegistrationObj = { registration: { DeviceReference: deviceId, Username: username, Password: password, VehicleReg: "" } };
        return $http.post(urlBase + 'RegisterDevice', RegistrationObj);
    };  
    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

Then i can use it in my controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope, RegistrationFactory) {
    RegistrationFactory.RegisterUser(username, password, $cordovaDevice.getUUID())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include some functions to make everything work...

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular
      .module('app', []) // dont forget the '[]' here
      .factory('authService', authService);

    authService.$inject = ['$firebaseAuth'];

    function authService($firebaseAuth) {
      var ref = new Firebase('https://[MY-FIREBASE].firebaseio.com');
      var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

        return {
            createUser: function(email,password) {
              auth.$createUser({
                  email: email,
                  password: password
              }).then(function(userData) {
                  $location.path('/people');
              }).catch(function(error) {
                  alert(error);
              })
            },

            connectFacebook: auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
                $location.path('/places');
            }).catch(function(error) {
                alert("Authentication failed:", error);
            }),

            removeUser: auth.$removeUser({
                email: vm.email,
                password: vm.password
            }).then(function() {
                alert('User removed');
            }).catch(function(error) {
                alert(error);
            })
        }
    }
}());
```

Then we wrap it all in an IIFE and remove any globals from the window.